# web.config redirecting non www to www with one route exception

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, redirect

Hello Im having trouble configuring my web.config file with a redirect rule.

My redirect rule now is

```
<rule name="Redirects to www.example.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />

</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
```

Now I want to exclude url https://example.com/some-url (and all url-s under this one) from the rule mentioned above. This rule should not redirect https://example.com/some-url to https://www.example.com/some-url.

So how do I exclude this url from the redirect rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add a condition like this (note: now edited):

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/some-url/(.*)" negate="true" />
```

to the list of conditions?

Edit: and set the conditions to "MatchAll" rather than "MatchAny"

Not tested, but seems like that may work?

(Note: Edited answer as First rule was definitely wrong; current version may work but still untested)

Comment: try removing the `logicalGrouping="MatchAll"` ?    (I'm just looking at what the IIS Rewrite module in IIS puts in web.config when I set this up - it seems that a 'MatchAll' rule is the default and is assumed if no logicalGrouping setting is specified)

Comment: Ah!  try this instead for the second rule `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/some-url$" negate="true" />`
`

Comment: {REQUEST_URI} must not contain domain :) I ended up with

`<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/api/(.*)" negate="true" />`

Comment: Glad I helped at least point in the right direction :) - I've amended the answer in line with your comment so it is now correct.